# How do I cast a decimal number to String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

325.234 to string?

is it toString()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way, concatenate it with an empty string:

```
325.234 + '';
```

Which will implicitly call `toString()` on the number.

You could also use:

```
String(325.234);
```

And:

```
325.234.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not just:

```
325.234.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

or `String(325.234)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 123.54
var string = number.toString();
```

The "toString()" method is called implicitly when you use a non-string as part of a string concatenation. Such as:

```
var newString = "Hello " + number;
```